# I can't update in the Google Play Store: Version error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play

I'm trying to update my app in the Google Play Store, but I can't, It send me this error:

```
This setting can not be published for the following reasons:
Do not allow a device to update the version of API levels in the range 15-18 API levels in the range 19+ pass from version 8 to version 7. This happens when
Screen layouts with [small, normal, large, xlarge] and
Features with [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
```

The message says something like the version is configured to API version 15-18, that is weird because this is my build.grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.7"
        applicationId 'xxx.xxxx.xxxxxx'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile(name:'android-widevine-plugin-4.2.8', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'android-sdk-4.2.8', ext:'aar')
}
```

The version of the app that is published is 7, so that is not the problem.

This is the build.gradle file of the last version I can upload to Google Play Store

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile files('lib/OoyalaSDK.jar')
}
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Do you have mutliple APKs? Can you post the current released gradle file.

Comment: Hi Ryan I only have one APK, How can I get the released gradle file?

Comment: You have an APK on the Google Play Store already right? Post the Gradle file associated with that APK, or the manifest file if you did not use Gradle before. This way we can see what changed.

Comment: The post has been updated with the requested information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dependencies, maybe one of them is restricting the max. version of the API.

```
compile(name:'android-widevine-plugin-4.2.8', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'android-sdk-4.2.8', ext:'aar')
```